# how to show date automatically after 15 days in text box using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have two text box here, one is published date and second is ending date.
When the user selects published date, i want to show the date in ending date that is 15 days after the published date.

E.g: if the user selects oct 1 2018 in published date, the oct 15 2018 must automatically display in ending date..

```
 <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Published Date</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="published_date" name="published_date" data-date="01-01-2017" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" class="datepicker span11">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Ending Date</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="ending_date" name="ending_date" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What have you tried already? `JavaScript` or `php` solution?

Comment: Welcome to [stack overflow's coding service](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you can use js to fetch the data from the first input box, add fifteen days to it and then populate the next field with it

Answer (score 1):

You can use this js snippet to add 15 days to a Date Object.

```
let date = new Date(document.getElementById("published_date").value); // making a date object with string
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 15); // setting date 15 days after
document.getElementById("ending_date").value = new_date.toISOString().slice(0, 10); // formatting to yyyy-mm-dd
```

Because the `Date` constructor in JS gets input with free-form strings, you can make a `Date` object with the string value of the `#published_date` element.

After making a `Date` object, use [**`Date.prototype.setDate()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) and [**`Date.prototype.getDate()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) to set the date 15 days after the initial date.

Finally set the `#ending_date` element's value with `yyyy-mm-dd` format with [**`Date.prototype.toISOString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) and slicing strings.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
var published_date = document.getElementById('published_date').value;
published_date = new Date(published_date);
ending_date = new Date(published_date.getTime() + (1000 * (3600 * 24 * 15)));

document.getElementById('ending_date').value = ending_date.getFullYear() + "-" + (ending_date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + (ending_date.getDate() < 10 ? "0" + ending_date.getDate() : ending_date.getDate());
```

`published_date.getTime() + (1000 * (3600 * 24 * 15))` adds up 15 days in milliseconds.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i have used date picker..so how do i use when the date is selected?

Comment: it worked..but i have to display when the date changed in data picker..

Comment: What date picker do you use? You need to know the event that the plugin triggers when date is selected. Find it out in its documentation. Once you know the event and its usage, just paste that code inside event function. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

use this javascript,

```
 <script>
    var date = new Date(document.getElementById("published_date").value);
   date.setDate(date.getDate() + 15);
   document.getElementById("ending_date").value = date

    </script>
```